# How to do sum unique ids with MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to work with the following data: I have a series of "logs" which list the `customer_id` with various info about the product purchased:

Each customer may have several "logs" (as each customer may have made several purchases). I can "count" the number of logs each customer has by using

```
> db.test.aggregate([{$group : {"_id" : "$customer_id", total_purchases : {$sum : 1}}}])
```

which outputs

```
{ "_id" : 7293, "total_purchases" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 8573, "total_purchases" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2734, "total_purchases" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 7334, "total_purchases" : 7 }
{ "_id" : 1239, "total_purchases" :12 }
{ "_id" : 8342, "total_purchases" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 9834, "total_purchases" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 0012, "total_purchases" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 7234, "total_purchases" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 8342, "total_purchases" : 5 }
...
```

So, customer "_id 7293" made three total purchases, customer "_id 8573" made one total purchases, etc.

I would like to know the total number of customers with total purchases greater than three. How does one "sum" the total number of customers?

At the moment, I know how to use `$match` to list the total number of customers with total purchases greater than three, i.e.

```
> db.test.aggregate([{$group : {"_id" : "$customer_id", total_purchases : {$sum : 1}}}]), {total_purchases : {"$gt" : 3}}])
```

which outputs

```
{ "_id" : 7334, "total_purchases" : 7 }
{ "_id" : 1239, "total_purchases" :12 }
{ "_id" : 8342, "total_purchases" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 1324, "total_purchases" : 6 }
{ "_id" : 9823, "total_purchases" : 9 }
...
```

How can I output just *one number*, the total number of customers with purchases greater than 3? What is the SQL equivalent of this? 
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you show sample document with the expected result?

Comment: @user3100115 I deleted the sample document. See the edit history, or this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019119/how-to-use-aggregation-for-mongodb-to-filter-based-on-and-or/35019403#35019403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage $match along with $project.

Something similar to:

```
db.log.aggregate([{      
    $group: {
         _id: "$customer_id",
         total_purchases: { 
              $sum: 1 
         }
     }, 
     { $match: { "total_purchases": { $gt: 3 }},
     { $project: { "_id": 0, "total_purchases": 1 }}    
 }}])
```

Comment: There's an error here with brackets. I think the correct ordering should be something like: `db.log.aggregate([
{$group: { _id: "$customer_id" , total_purchases: {$sum: 1}}}, 
{$match: { "total_purchases": { "$gt": 3 }}},
{$project: { "_id": 0, "total_purchases": 1 }}])`

However, this does not count the total number of customers than have an order greater than three.