# How to use aggregation for MongoDB to filter based on $and/$or?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I don't quite understand to use `$or` or `$and` operators with MongoDB.

Let's say I have following data:

```
{
    "_id" : "0211dd50-6283-11e6-be4b-01259186ebdc",
    "customer_id" : 75832,
    "prod_display_id" : "8c890b9c-7824-11e5-9cf1-24519096eb0c",
    "record_ids" : [
        ObjectId("1377ki5f8782b634fbf92b07b"),
        ObjectId("6283gf5f922b634fbf32b07a"),
        ObjectId("9913zd5f234b634fbf22b07c")
    ],
    "create_dt" : ISODate("2014-01-12T13:31:42.740Z")
}, 
{
    "_id" : "3454ke24-9372-11e6-be4b-01259186ebdc",
    "customer_id" : 75832,
    "prod_display_id" : "2d723b5c-8823-77y5-9cf1-00259096eb0c",
    "record_ids" : [
        ObjectId("1377ki5f8782b634fbf92b07b")
    ],
    "create_dt" : ISODate("2014-03-12T15:45:01.650Z")
}, 
{
    "_id" : "0211dd50-6283-23t6-it84-63957834kjhdd",
    "customer_id" : 11486,
    "prod_display_id" : "8c890b9c-7824-11e5-9cf1-00259096eb0c",
    "record_ids" : [
        ObjectId("9870kr5f9234b745fbf23g12b")
    ],
    "create_dt" : ISODate("2015-02-23T16:23:53.112Z")
}
....
```

Now, I would like to find all of the users that have certain `record_id's`. Lets say I want all users that have `ObjectId(....)` OR `ObjectId(....)` (that is, one or the other.)

I think the correct aggregation operator is:

```
> db.collection.aggregate([{ $project: { content_id : {$or : [ObjectId("...."), ObjectId("...")]}}}])
```

Similarly, the AND operation should be

```
> db.collection.aggregate([{ $project: { content_id : {$and : [ObjectId("...."), ObjectId("...")]}}}])
```

I am wrong however! If I run the above, both `$project` operations outputs *all* files, regardless whether the certain ObjectId() exists or not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all you don't need aggregation for this `.find()` will be enough. I don't think this will even work.

Comment: @user3100115 How would you use `.find()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need aggregation for this; and you don't need the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) operator.

To find to find all "users" that have certain `ObjectId` in "record_ids" simply use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator.

```js
db.collection.find( { "record_ids": { "$all": <array of record_ids> } } )
```

To find to find all "users" that have all `ObjectId`s in "record_ids" simply use the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) operator

```js
db.collection.find( { "record_ids": { "$in": <array of record_ids> } } )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't require any aggregate to run such simple queries.

```
    db.collection.find({$or : [{"content_id":ObjectId("....")},{"content_id": ObjectId("...")} ] } )

OR

    db.collection.find({"content_id":{ "$in":[ObjectId("...."),ObjectId("....")] }  } )
```

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/